# Change misplaced file extensions

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, filenames

I have accidentally renamed a large number of my files with an `.mp4` extension. Luckily the original extension has been preserved within the filename (e.g. `simon.says.nfo.mp4`)

How would i now remove the mp4 part from just these files?

Due to the naming system I have, I cannot just do a find for `*.*.mp4` which would be a lot easier with a find/replace combo.

Comment: Will `*.nfo.mp4` match all affected files? Will `*.*.mp4` match non-affected files?

Comment: Can you please add examples of files which end in `.mp4` which should **not** have the `.mp4` removed?

Comment: example below                                                                                        Iron Man 2.mp4     Iron Man 2.mp4.unknown.ignore                         Iron Man 2.nfo.mp4      Iron Man 2.orig.nfo.mp4
Iron Man 2.mp4.mp4     Iron Man 2.nfo     Iron Man 2.orig.nfo Iron Man 2.unknown.ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rename" is a utility that does exactly what you need:

```
rename 's/.mp4//' *.mp4
```

man rename for other info

Comment: Will that touch files without the `.nfo` part of the `.nfo.mp4` suffix?

Comment: the command will apply the replacement command "s/.mp4//" to all files matching *.mp4. that means that it will only remove the .mp4 part. you could read 2 lines of man page to understand it

Comment: If that's a _regular_ regular expression, it might be worth anchoring it to the end of the line and escaping the dot?

Comment: yes you can. 

    rename "s/\.mp4$//" *.mp4

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `.mp4` extension of all files with the `.nfo.mp4` extension in the current directory:

```
for fname in ./*.nfo.mp4; do
  newfname="$( basename "$fname" .mp4 )"
  mv -i "$fname" "$newfname"
done
```

The `basename` utility both removes the path (leaves just the filename) and is able to remove a suffix in one go. We can remove the path here without adding it in again since we're only interested in the current directory. The equivalent effect would be had by using the `newfname="${fname%.mp4}"` parameter expansion (which removes the `.mp4` suffix but doesn't strip out the initial path from `$fname`, although this isn't a problem here).

I'm using `mv -i` so that you get to manually confirm any `mv` operation that would otherwise overwrite an existing file.

For testing, the following will only print out what would have happened:

```
for fname in ./*.nfo.mp4; do
  newfname="$( basename "$fname" .mp4 )"
  printf 'Want to rename "%s" into "%s"\n' "$fname" "$newfname"
  ## mv -i "$fname" "$newfname"
done
```

Comment: Using basename is overkill!  Just use `newfname=${fname%.mp4}`

Comment: @icarus Yes, that works well too. I used `basename` for clarity here. It would also be faster to use your suggestion, but I wonder how important speed would be in this particular case.

Comment: @icarus I'll mention it as an alternative.